# Dockerfile showing error "failed to compute cache key: "/Pipfile.lock" not found"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pipenv

Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get -y upgrade && \
 apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends make && \
 apt-get clean && \
 rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
 pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
 pip install --no-cache-dir pipenv

WORKDIR /sphinxtechnicalwriting

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /sphinxtechnicalwriting/

RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
```

Error Displayed :

```
=> CANCELED [2/5] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get -y upgrade &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends make &&     apt-get clean &&       0.6s
 => CACHED [3/5] WORKDIR /sphinxtechnicalwriting                                                                                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [4/5] COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /sphinxtechnicalwriting/                                                                                   0.0s
------
 > [4/5] COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /sphinxtechnicalwriting/:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/Pipfile.lock" not found: not found
```

Tried clearing pipfile cache but now it gave cancelled in the 1st run command as well

Comment: Does the `Pipfile.lock` exist on your host system in the same directory as the `Pipfile` (and, probably, the `Dockerfile`)?

Comment: yes this error got resolved by installing pipenv lock  separately.
but other error is still not resolved

Answer (score 0):

When you build your docker image

at step

```
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /sphinxtechnicalwriting/
```

files `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` will be copied from same folder where you launch `docker build ...` (or other command you launch to build) to the docker image.

Error says that there are no such files at source folder.

Comment: now error:
 [2/5] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get -y upgrade &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends make &&     apt-get clean &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&     pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip &&     pip install --no-cache-dir pipenv:
#6 23.25 Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
#6 23.25 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
#6 23.25 is only available from another source
#6 23.25 E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate
------

Comment: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get -y upgrade &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends make &&     apt-get clean &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&     pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip &&     pip install --no-cache-dir pipenv]: exit code: 100

Comment: @TaruArora: If you have another error that you need help with, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same bug today, the fix was to remove `Pipfile.lock` from my `.dockerignore` file, that's why Docker could not find the Pipfile.